npm is throwing an error code ERR_REQUIRE_ESM after upgrading from older version
I am working on a personal website using Firebase as a host and as I was working on installing everything I noticed that there was an error being thrown, while it didn't seem to have any resulting issues as the setup of everything still worked fine I went ahead and fixed this. The error was just saying that npm was out of date, which yeah fair enough I was running an early build 10 from when I first installed NodeJS on my system and never updated it since.
Went ahead and updated to latest non LTS build, restarted PC and then did an npm init - setting up a "Learning" Project to relearn React and such before running on my actual Firebase Project.
And then the error gets throw:
npm error code ERR_REQUIRE_ESM
npm error require() of ES Module C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\p-map\index.js from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js not supported.
npm error Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Bagheera\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-14T09_26_02_880Z-debug-0.log        

With the following Log file resulting in:
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.8.2
2 info using node@v20.18.0
3 silly config load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc
4 silly config load:file:E:\VSCode Repo\deadlock-builder\.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:C:\Users\Bagheera\.npmrc
6 silly config load:file:C:\Users\Bagheera\.npm-global\etc\npmrc
7 verbose title npm init
8 verbose argv "init"
9 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Bagheera\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-14T09_26_02_880Z-
10 verbose logfile C:\Users\Bagheera\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-14T09_26_02_880Z-debug-0.log
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 14 files
12 verbose stack Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\p-map\index.js from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js not supported.
12 verbose stack Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
12 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js:22:14)
13 error code ERR_REQUIRE_ESM
14 error require() of ES Module C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\node_modules\p-map\index.js from C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js not supported.
14 error Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
15 verbose cwd E:\VSCode Repo\relearn
16 verbose os Windows_NT 10.0.22631
17 verbose node v20.18.0
18 verbose npm  v10.8.2
19 verbose exit 1
20 verbose code 1
21 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Bagheera\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-14T09_26_02_880Z-debug-0.log

Well, this is a problem so I thought it might be an issue with the latest version, so I uninstalled that and dropped down to LTS
This error shows up constantly when doing anything with npm with only 8 verbose argv line changing for the command being used i.e. npm init npm install x (x being a package name)
There is Peter Mortensen's post and related Roope Kuisma's post of similar errors however both are talking about code within their projects already, I am just unable to even run anything using NPM except running just npm
Update: This actually seems to be an issue with the VSCode Terminal, running commands via Powershell, CMD etc works fine

Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a [mre]?

What version of node did you come from?
